# Hating container divs and trying to use HTML5 way

Tags: html, css

I recently started some web programming/designing and I'm facing this problem.
In HTML5 you have these cool tags like `section` and `header` and `footer` and everything.

- My first question raises here: do they behave (in a CSS context) **exactly** like `div`s?

Moving to a more specific problem, I have to create a website with a simple `header -> content (section) -> footer` structure (*note: I'm no interested in IE compatibility*). I would like the central section to expand (vertically) as much as it can, until it meets the footer.
The "until it meets the footer" part can be achieved through some `padding-bottom` but what about the "extending as much as possible" part? Note that the footer should stop when, while resizing the page, it meets the section.

I mean, I know with some `div`s life would be easier, but is it possible that with today standards I still have to wrap the whole page in a `<div id="container">` tag?
So the second question arises...

- Can't I achieve what I would achieve by using both `html` and `body` as containers of a `div#container` by making the `html` be the `html + body` part and the `body` be the `div#container`?

I hope my question is clear, I know I tend to digress when I write.

**Note** for clarity, I will add my HTML structure and some highlights from my CSS here, but I don't know if they're relevant to the question.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head...>
<body>
    <header id="page_header">
        stuff in the header...
    </header>

    <section id="page_content">
        stuff in the main section...
    </section>    

    <footer id="page_footer">
        an almost-sticky footer...
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    background-image: url('../res/img/bg-light.png');
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    width: 900px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
}

section#page_content {
    min-height: 400px; // ? does this stop the footer from being dragged over the content when resizing?
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

footer#page_footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**Micro-note** why the hell my `body` doesn't start from the exact top of the page, while starting a few pixels from the top? Just asking.

Comment: Thank you, so question #1 is done. That however makes me think about how much `div`s can be useful this days (in order to markup content, which is what HTML is for, not for styling purposes).

Comment: In regards to your "micro-note": Have you tried re-setting your `<header>`, `<section>` and `<footer>` styling (in particular `padding` and `margin` to `0`)?  Or, are you using a CSS reset that also targets HTML5 elements?

Comment: it's my opinion that `<div>`s are still very much useful, especially for styling. Using `<header>` `<section>` and such are great for code readability though.

Comment: Just because we now have new elements, doesn't mean the old ones shouldn't be used any more. `<section>` has a very specific semantic meaning, which is different from `<div>`.  For a more detailed explanation, take a look at: http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-section/

Comment: I don't mean old ones shouldn't be used, it's just that they often don't mark up the content as much as new ones do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, most tags such as `<section>`, `<header>`, and `<footer>` behave very similarly to `<div>`'s. They're very much up to you to determine how you use them. However, you shouldn't overlook the importance of using `<div>`s, especially for styling. I've seen a few CSS frameworks (twitter Bootstrap and Blueprint come to mind) that supply you with a `<div class="container">`  for styling. For readability though, `<section>`, `<footer>`, `<header>`, and also `<article>` can be very beneficial.

By all means, use HTML5 where possible and where compatible, but I believe you'll always be able to find a useful and beneficial way of using `<div>`s in your web code now days.

That's just my opinion.

I found [this link](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-section/) when I searched. It may shed some light on the issue better than I can. It points out several distinct places to use `<div>`s over newer HTML5 tags.

You *could* use `<html>` or `<body>` tags in place of a div container. There's certainly nothing *wrong* with it, and it may even make your code slightly cleaner. I, personally, always use some sort of container, though. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354739/why-should-i-use-a-container-div-in-html) that I believe answers that pretty clearly.

Also, the body should fill the screen. If it's not, check your CSS.

Comment: Spot on. If an HTML5 Structural element fits the bill one should feel the freedom to use it (with the proper class!). Say **no** to semantic guilt!

Answer (score 0):

The elements you mentioned are block level elements and, as far as styling goes, will behave the same as divs but that's as far as that goes because some of those elements are sectioning elements and, therefore, its contents behave somewhat differently as far as structure goes.

Yes, you could always use the body as a wrapper for content but now we have the [main](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) element if that proves helpful. While the html element is styleable, its rather limited, but the body element is also a block element.

divs are still quite useful as they can be used as generic content containers and can thus be used for styling content without disrupting sectioning caused by using something else.