# Bootstrap col-span specifications

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, col

I have a specification document which states - Bootstrap
Col Spans -2 (.col-span-2). So does that mean I should use col-xs-2 and col-lg-2 while writing the html class names? Or does that mean I should use col-lg-6?

Also, can I use multiple containers in a single bootstrap html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

span-2 would be col-md-2. By my experience Span was supported in Bootstrap V2.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid look at the Grid Options of the documentation.

Also how come you would like multiple containers? would it not be feasible to use divs?

(Added answer due to unable to comment) Trying to help instead of providing the perfect answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just mean instead of adding a blank div, can i add container or is it not a good practice?

Comment: Here is a good answer that I think might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/354752/4184136
In my time I have always used one container for my content and then several div's inside the container. I have never come across any implications or limitations doing it this way.